# reusing an address how can I get the confirmations

Tags: api

I would like to reuse an address I was thinking of using blockchain.info api which returns the amount sent to the address if confirmation reach the set parameter. When I send more BTC to the same address the confirmation parameter no longer works. Is the another solution for this?

https://blockchain.info/q/getreceivedbyaddress/adressxxxxxxxxxxx?confirmations=4

Comment: Don't reuse addresses, don't use blockchain.Info, don't use this party APIs.

Comment: Jannes is there a free api provider that you can recommend ?

Comment: Everything starts with running your own full node: bitcoincore.org